# Can someone explain to me NaN in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, numbers, nan

I just found a bug in some number manipulations in my program and I'm getting a `FloatDomainError (NaN)`

So I started logging the number passed in with:

```
if(metric.is_a?(Numeric))
  self.metric = metric
else
  LOGGER.warn("metric #{metric} is not a number")
  self.metric=0
end
```

But the number being passed in is `NaN` which apparently `is_a?(Numeric)` as I don't get my log warning, and it passes metric on to my metric= method, which is where I get my `FloatDomainError`

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it seem semantically wrong to have an `NaN` (Not A Number) be of type Numeric ??  Can someone explain this to me?

BTW using Jruby-1.4.1

Comment: If there were only some Indian restaurants nearby .. :) could not help :D

Comment: we'd have a delicious answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating point numbers define -INFINITY +INFINITY and NotANumber to make it possible to react to lets say division by zero. you can also calculate with these for eg 2 + INF = INF

NaN isn't a uniqe ruby feature, they are numeric in java, c++, ... too

Answer (score 7):

I think that making NaN a number makes perfectly sense...

try 0.0 / 0.0 in irb -> the result is NaN (which in this case is infinity)

Infinity is mathematically kind of a number, but still, you can't express it with a datatype... in math you use a special symbol too...

PS: You can use metric.nan? to check it... then it should work as you expect...

Comment: Fair enough, I just think semantically that 'Not a Number' is a Number is a bit weird...

Comment: @brad: well, I agree, the name for that state is not well chosen... :)